# Externally linked images - How to prevent cross site scripting

Tags: xss

On my site, I want to allow users to add reference to images which are hosted anywhere on the internet. These images can then be seen by all users of my site. As far as I understand, this could open the risk of cross site scripting, as in the following scenario:
User A adds a link to a gif which he hosts on his own webserver. This webserver is configured in such a way, that it returns javascript instead of the image. 
User B opens the page containg the image. Instead of seeing the image, javascript is executed.

My current security messures are currently such, that both on save and open, all content is encoded.
I am using asp.net(c#) on the server and a lot of jquery on the client to build ui elements, including the generation of image tags.

Is this fear of mine correct? Am I missing any other important security loopholes here? And most important of all, how do I prevent this attack? The only secure way I can think of right now, is to webrequest the image url on the server and check if it contains anything else than binary data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the file is indeed an image won't help. An attacker could return one thing when the server requests and another when a potential victim makes the same request.

Having said that, as long as you restrict the URL to only ever be printed inside the src attribute of an img tag, then you have a CSRF flaw, but not an XSS one.

Someone could for instance create an "image" URL along the lines of:
http://yoursite.com/admin/?action=create_user&un=bob&pw=alice
Or, more realistically but more annoyingly; http://yoursite.com/logout/

If all sensitive actions (logging out, editing profiles, creating posts, changing language/theme) have tokens, then an attack vector like this wouldn't give the user any benefit.

But going back to your question; unless there's some current browser bug I can't think of you won't have XSS. Oh, remember to ensure their image URL doesn't include odd characters. ie: an image URL of `"><script>alert(1)</script><!-`- may obviously have bad effects. I presumed you know to escape that.

Comment: Someone could simply use javascript:alert('XSS'); inside the image src tag though. (That is if you don't check it's actually an url)

Answer (score 0):

Your approach to security is incorrect.
Don't approach the topic as "I have a user input, so how can I prevent XSS".  Rather approach it like it this: "I have user input - it should be restrictive as possible - i.e. allowing nothing through".  Then based on that allow only what's absolutely essential - plain-text strings thoroughly sanitized to prevent anything but a URL, and the specific, necessary characters for URLS only.  Then Once it is sanitized I should only allow images. Testing for that is hard because it can be easily tricked.  However, it should still be tested for.  Then because you're using an input field you should make sure that everything from javascript scripts and escape characters, HTML, XML and SQL injections are all converted to plaintext and rendered harmless and useless. Consider your users as being both idiots and hackers - that they'll input everything incorrectly and try to hack something into your input space.

Aside from that you may run into som legal issues with regard to copyright.  Copyrighted images generally may not be used on other people's sites without the copyright owner's consent and permission - usually obtained in writing (or email).  So allowing users the opportunity to simply lift images from a site could run the risk of allowing them to take copyrighted material and reposting it on your site without permission which is illegal.  Some sites are okay with citing the source, others require a fee to be paid, and others will sue you and bring your whole  domain down for copyright infringement.